# Can we merge the macintosh and the osx tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, useless-tags

Can we merge [macintosh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macintosh) and [osx](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) where osx is the master tag? Those tags seem to have the same meaning, and it is unnecessary to have both.

Comment: I'm not sure: one might be interested in other OSs running on Macs and OSX running on non-Apple hardware.

Comment: @muru there is the hacintosh (not a typo) tag which is for Mac osx operating systems on non-macs and both the Macintosh and the osx tag are for Apple Macs with Mac operating systems.

Comment: I know what Hackintosh is. Have you read [tag:macintosh]'s info? It's for Macs whether or not you're running OSX.

Comment: @muru if it's the hardware that they're asking about, then it belongs on super user SE, and almost all of the Macintosh tagged questions are ones that should be tagged osx

Comment: Whatever for would I ask on [su] if I'm interested in running Linux on a Mac?

Comment: Do you know that the EFI implementation on Macs was broken for years, and that's why Ubuntu had images tagged `mac` because of that?

Comment: @muru if it's Linux on a Mac, why would it matter if it's a Mac? It would only matter if it's hardware related, which means it belongs on super user. And actually, the main reason I want them to be synonyms is not that they are synonyms, but that the Macintosh tag is so commonly used when osx is what should be used

Comment: @John, where did you get the idea that hardware related questions are automatically off-topic on this site?  I don't believe that's the case at all.

Comment: I really should dig up a copy of A/UX so I can ask a [tag:macintosh] question that is indisputably not [tag:osx].

Comment: Is this more relevant now with the 'X' going away? (`OS X` becoming `macOS`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm torn between the fact that there really is a meaningly difference in the taxonomy here (and at least historically, it was relevant to this site) and the obvious issue that people suck at picking appropriate tags.

I think the solution is probably to make it harder for people to use the wrong tags without having the correct ones put in front of them. For example a [mac](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) could be made as a synonym of [osx](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) to catch people that start to type and don't know where to start. This way the first tag suggested to them when they start typing `ma...` will be the tag most likely to be correct. Additionally the [macintosh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macintosh) tag excerpt could be expanded with a blatant explanation/warning of what hardware is covered by that moniker. Currently reading what comes up in the popup won't tip off most people about how to use it.

Additionally the tag summary for [osx](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) would benefit from being simplified so people aren't so shy of using it.